# Natural refrigeration

Tags: thermodynamics

I have an electricity-free pot-in-pot refrigerator that uses evaporative cooling to keep the inside cool. However, I live in a very humid place, so the rate of evaporation will be low and hence this won't be as effective for cooling. Are there ways to increase the rate of evaporation? Is there a way to decrease the pressure of the water between the 2 pots (without using electricity) in order to increase the rate of evaporation? And of course, I have constraint on how big of a refrigerator I can keep, so increasing the pot's size (and hence the surface area of the water) isn't the ideal option.

Thanks!

Comment: You could increase the rate of evaporation by heating the system, but that would be rather counterproductive. You could try pointing a fan at it.

Comment: Einstein's gas absorption fridge.  http://www.treehugger.com/clean-technology/new-solar-refrigerator-prototype-from-chile.html

Answer (score 1):

Your only hope is to place a fan in the system to move ever-so-slightly less humid air into the system to enhance evaporation.

Note that there are refrigerators that run on a gas flame rather than by an electric compressor; these are called ammonia-absorption refrigerators and are commonly used in travel trailers, motor homes, and remote places where refrigeration is needed but electricity is unavailable. They can be made to run on kerosene, propane or natural gas and are very reliable because they have no moving parts.